# Acces array variables from a json file in Unity

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I am trying to read the variables of a json array that is read in a Unity script.
This is what I have:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using System;

public class json_example02 : MonoBehaviour
{

    public string[] newObject;
    
    void Start()
    {

        Debug.Log("jsonScript start");

        // create object
        jasonClass newObject = new jasonClass();

        // read from json file: succesful
        string jsonread = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + "/valuesexample.json");  
        newObject = JsonUtility.FromJson<jasonClass>(jsonread);

        Debug.Log(newObject.Values.Length);// reads correctly

        // trying to acces variables here, but it returns empty
        Debug.Log("Values: " + newObject.Values[0]);
        Debug.Log("Values: " + newObject.Values[1]);
        Debug.Log("Values: " + newObject.Values[2]);

        // write to file: succesful
        string jsonwrite = JsonUtility.ToJson(newObject);
        File.WriteAllText(Application.dataPath + "/saveFileReturn.json", jsonwrite);
       
    }


    [Serializable]
    public class jasonClass
    {
        public Valuesarray[] Values;
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class Valuesarray
    {
        public string Text;
        //public string Text2;
    }
}
```

This is the format of the json read file:

```
{"Values":[{
"Text":"A"
},
{
"Text":"B"
},
{
"Text":"C"
},
{
"Text":"D"
},
{
"Text":"E"
}]
}
```

Checking for read and write into another file. Output:

```
{"Values":[{"Text":"A"},{"Text":"B"},{"Text":"C"},{"Text":"D"},{"Text":"E"}]}
```

All good so far but I don't understand how to read the individual variables by indexnumber, like so:

```
Debug.Log("Values: " + newObject.Values[0]);
```

Which returns empty.
How can I access these variables by index number?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there!

Since your Valuesarray class has the Text variable, your code should call it:

```
    Debug.Log("Values: " + newObject.Values[0].Text);
    Debug.Log("Values: " + newObject.Values[1].Text);
    Debug.Log("Values: " + newObject.Values[2].Text);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! I didn't expect this solution, but it's definitely helping me to develop the script further.

Comment: @Hieronymus Best of luck with your project. Cheers!